# How to read and display multidimentional array from a file

Tags: c++

My first problem is if I'm even reading the components of the file into the array correctly.  Then I need to display the array like the file with row and column indicators.  I thought I was close but I can't get the indicators to display properly and the contents of the array don't seem to be displaying properly.  I'm still new to c++ so this has been difficult for me.

Here's the input file:

```
X X   X X X
X X   X X X
X X   X X X
O O   O O O
O O   O O O
O O   O O O
O O   O O O
O O   O O O
O O   O O O
O O   O O O
O O   A A A
O O   A A O
O A   A O O
X X   X X X
O O   O O O
O A   A O O
O A   A O O
O O   A O O
O A   O O O
O O   A O O
O A   O O O
O O   A A A
O O   O O O
O O   O O O
A A   A A O
O A   O O O
A A   A A A
A A   A A A
A A   A A A
O A   O O O
O O   A O O
O O   A O O
X X   A A O
A A   A A O
A A   A A A
A A   A A A
O O   A A A
X X   A A A
```

And here's the code I have so far (With some unnecessary stuff removed):

```
string origin, destination, airplane;
        int month, day, year, seat, option;
        char seats[5][38];
        ifstream infile;
        ifstream outfile;
        cout << "\nPlease enter the airplane you wish to board: ";
        cin >> airplane;
        cout << "\nWould you like to: \n1) Pick your own seat \n2)Let to program pick your seat" << endl;
        cin >> option;
        airplane.insert(4, ".txt");
        infile.open(airplane.c_str());
        if (infile.fail())
        {
            cout << airplane << " does not exist." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 38; j++)
                    infile >> seats[i][j];
        }
        switch (option)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    cout << "\tA C   D E F" << endl;
                    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
                        for (int col = 0; col < 38; col+=5)
                            cout << seats[row][col] << " " << seats[row][col+1] << "   " << seats[row][col+2] << " " << seats[row][col+3] << " " << seats[row][col+4] << endl;
                    cout << "\n";
                    
                    break;
                }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- The way you read from the file is [almost always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons):

  ```
  while (!infile.eof())
  ```

  The problem is that `infile.eof()` will not return `true` until it's actually tried to read passed the last character in the file, so you'll get one extra iteration in the `while` loop which means that the below part will be executed twice:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < 38; j++)
          infile >> seats[i][j];
  ```
- I suggest separating the stream I/O from the rest of the logic. You could define a `Row` that only holds the seats for one row:

  ```
  struct Row {
      char seats[5];
  };
  ```
- With that, add overloads for `operator>>` and `operator<<` to read/write one `Row` from/to streams:

  ```
  // Read one Row from an `istream`, like your `infile`:
  std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Row& r) {
      for(char& seat : r.seats) is >> seat;   // a range-based for loop
      return is;
  }

  // Write one Row to an `ostream`, like `std::cout`
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Row& r) {
      return os
          << r.seats[0] << ' ' << r.seats[1] << "   "
          << r.seats[2] << ' ' << r.seats[3] << ' ' << r.seats[4];
  }
  ```
- Reading from `infile` to fill an array of `Row` could then look like this:

  ```
  Row rows[38];

  for(Row& r : rows) {                    // A range-based for loop again
      if(!(infile >> r)) {                // check that extracting the Row suceeds
          std::cout << "aircraft file corrupted\n";
          return 1;
      }
  }
  ```
- Writing the result to screen (requires `#include <iomanip>` for `std::setw()`):

  ```
  std::cout << "   A C   D E F\n";

  for(size_t idx = 0; idx < std::size(rows); ++idx) {
      std::cout << std::setw(2) << idx+1 << ' ' << rows[idx] << '\n';
  }
  ```